# 'openssl/conf.h' file not found error on on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, vapor

I am currently attempting to run an xcode project that creates a Vapor server for the ios application, however, I get an error complaining that 'openssl/conf.h' file is not found. I also get Could not build Objective-C module 'CNIOOpenSSL' on the import package, but I suspect that this is linked to the file not being found by the compiler. I have already brew installed vapor using these instructions [https://stackoverflow.com/que[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/que%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px4vP.jpg)stions/43070534/openssl-ctls-trouble-with-vapor-2, but no luck. I also installed openssl and libressl, but same results. Any suggestions on what I may be missing? I've linked screenshots of the error below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHx5W.png)

Comment: Have you installed `pkg-config` via brew and what architecture are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was installing old version of openssl - openssl 1.1 and setting

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```